# Ruby ternary operator structure

Tags: ruby, ternary

```
puts bool ? "true" : "false"
```

is proper, but

```
bool ? puts "true" : puts "false"
```

is not.  Can somebody explain to me why this is?

Side note:

```
bool ? ( puts "true" ) : ( puts "false" )
```

works fine as well.

Comment: What to explain? Is obvious logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't put the parentheses on a method call, Ruby assumes you want everything to the end of the line to be the arguments.  That is to say, these calls are equivalent (and invalid):

```
bool ? puts "true" : puts "false"
bool ? puts("true" : puts "false")
```